# VB.NET Property as StringDictionary?

Tags: vb.net, properties, stringdictionary

I'm trying to create a new property with a type of StringDictionary but when I use the property like a stringdictionary variable I am getting an error.
The goal is to NOT use a variable, I need to use a property for this. Behind the scenes I am saving the stringdictionary value to a global user-ID indexed collection. Here's the code that creates the property and attempts to get and set:

```
Public Property MaxLenDict As StringDictionary()
    Get
        Return GetFromCollection("MaxLenDict")
    End Get
    Set(Value As StringDictionary())
        SaveToCollection("MaxLenDict", Value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub ExampleSub()
    If MaxLenDict("hello world") = "" Then MaxLenDict.Add("Hello World", "I'm Here")
End Sub
```

Get this error in ExampleSub "StringDictionary cannot be converted to string" in the IF statement on this code:

```
MaxLenDict("hello world")=""
```

So how do I successfully make and use a property as a stringdictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property is of type `StringDictionary()` (an array!), not `StringDictionary`.

I’m not sure that using `StringDictionary` is advised in the first place, though. The class is simply a remnant from pre-generics versions of .NET. Use `Dictionary(Of String, String)` instead.